# Send data between two pico with LoRa

Tags: python, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, lora

I am trying to send data from a Pico Raspberry Pi to another Pico through an SX1262, but I can't send it.

I already tried [the ping pong example](https://github.com/sammachin/micropySX126X), but the SX1262 library gives me errors in the Thonny IDE.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 19, in
>
> File "/lib/sx1262.py", line 27, in begin
>
> File "/lib/sx126x.py", line 115, in begin
>
> File "/lib/sx126x.py", line 240, in reset
>
> File "/lib/sx126x.py", line 389, in standby
>
> File "/lib/sx126x.py", line 1270, in SPIwriteCommand
>
> File "/lib/sx126x.py", line 1287, in SPItransfer
>
> TypeError: object with buffer protocol required

Then we tried to use AT commands, but there is no response ([code](https://techtotinker.blogspot.com/2021/03/exploring-lora-rylr896-with-micropython.html)). We don't want to use LoRaWAN.

Can you please help if you found the solution?

Comment: The library has been updated.  That was due to non-byte format being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it works: try this
https://github.com/ehong-tl/micropySX126X